# Adding css resource to a QuickTip in ExtJS not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs

I have a listener for a button that creates and attaches a QuickTip to that button like this:

```
onSomeButtonClick: function (button, e, eOpts) {
    var flag = foo();
    if (flag) {
        var tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.QuickTip', {
        hideDelay: 2000,
        header: false,
        cls: 'successTip' 
    });

    tip.update('Saved');
    tip.showBy(button);
}
```

The css resource looks like this:

```
.successTip 
{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: #9EE853;
    background-color: #D6FFD6;
}
```

My problem is that css properties are not applied unless I add !important to each property which I read is a very bad practice. What I also did was to browse through the element markup when it is created in the browser and what I thought was going to work was:

```
.successTip .x-tip-default 
{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: #9EE853;
    background-color: #D6FFD6;
}
```

I am almost certain it has to do something with these css classes like .x-tip-default, but cannot manage to get it to work. Here is the representation of the component in the browser:

```
<div class="x-tip successTip x-layer x-tip-default x-border-box" id="quicktip-1282" style="width: 114px; height: 33px; right: auto; left: 170px; top: 105px; z-index: 19000; display: none;">
    <div id="quicktip-1282-body" data-ref="body" class="x-tip-body x-tip-body-default x-tip-body-default x-noborder-trbl" role="presentation" style="width: 104px; height: 23px; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
        <div id="quicktip-1282-outerCt" data-ref="outerCt" class="x-autocontainer-outerCt" role="presentation">
                <div id="quicktip-1282-innerCt" data-ref="innerCt" style="" class="x-autocontainer-innerCt" role="presentation">Properties saved</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div role="presentation" class="x-tip-anchor x-tip-anchor-top" id="ext-element-75" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
</div>
```

Edit: I am new to css and don't really know how the classes work so even if you cannot provide an answer I would be grateful for a resource on that. I could not find one myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to define your own UI for your "success" tooltip. You would define your UI in the SASS file with the parameters from [the documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.tip.QuickTip-css_mixin-extjs-tip-ui), and then instead of giving your component a cls, give it a ui:

```
var tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.QuickTip', {
    hideDelay: 2000,
    header: false,
    ui: 'success-ui'
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, it is much appreciated! Just a question - defining a custom UI will not interfere with the theme I am using, right?

Comment: It will only be used if you reference it in a component (as above). Simply defining it will not change anything about your theme.